# migrar sitio a dominio principal en wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cpanel

Tengo un problema que no se bien como encarar. Hice varios cambios en un sitio, vendria a ser mobie.cl. Lo hice sobre un subdominio que tenia pensando despues migrar al dominio principal. el subdominio es mobie.cl/www1. El problema que tengo es que.. nunca pude lograr la migracion a mobie.cl. Ahora mismo tengo una redireccion del dominio principal a mobie.cl/www1.
La web original fue hecha por otro desarrollador y estaba llena de errores y problemas. Cuando entro desde softaculous tengo un alerta sobre el dominio principal que dice "archivos de instalacion no encontrados" y no me deja hacer nada con el sitio mas que borrarlo o desinstalarlo. Es estuvo desde que agarre la web.

[image: ERROR SOFTACULOUS]

Mi duda es como puedo puedo solucionar la migracion? necesito tener la web en el dominio principal.
Intente usar duplicator en el mobie.cl/www1 pero siempre me salta un error sobre el tiempo de conexion... ademas no estoy segura si esa seria la solucion. Es posible clonar la web y subir el instalador y el otro archivo desde c-panel a public_html que es el directorio root de mobie.cl? mobie.www1 tambien esta en public_html PERO en una subcarpeta...No se, la verdad estoy bastante perdida entre todo lo que estuve leyendo... asi que cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

**TODAS LAS CARPETAS QUE HAY EN PUBLIC_HTML**

[image: CARPETA PUBLIC_HTML]

[image: TODOS LAS SUBCARPETAS DE PUBLIC_HTML QUE YA ESTABAN DESDE ANTES. WWW1 ES LA QUE TIENE EL SITIO ACTUALIZADO]

**CARPETA DE WWW1**
[image: CARPETAS DE WWW1]

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de manera manual, moviendo los archivos de la carpeta del sub dominio a la carpeta del dominio principal, luego cambias en la base de datos, la url y como ultimo paso, podrías ingresar al WordPress y en enlaces permanentes, configurarlo nuevamente para que se aplique en todo el sitio web y la migración estaría completa.

Recuerda antes de hacer la prueba, quitar el redireccionamiento del dominio principal.

Comment: okey, Pregunta.. esto lo hago desde C-panel? voy a la carpeta www1 y apreto mover y muevo todo a public_html?

Comment: Claro, si puedes hacerlo de esa manera

Comment: hola! disculpa que te vuelva a molestar.. hice todo esto pero por alguna razon me sigue redirigiendo a mobie.cl/www1. Es mas, cuando hago algun cambio medio que se rompe la pagina... lo cambie desde wp_options, desde los enlaces permanentes, desde wp-config.. Cuando movi los archivos a public_html el sitio mobie.cl en softaculouss desaparecio.. asumo que es porque es identico al de mobie.cl/www1 y los junto pero, no se. estoy perdidisima porque pense que iba a ser algo simple

Comment: Tranqui... hiciste la edición de las url en la base de datos?